# Python datasets library can't automatically load_dataset due to network

Tags: python, dataset

I tried this

```py
>>> from datasets import load_dataset
>>> eli5 = load_dataset("eli5", split="train_asks[:5000]")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 1671, in load_dataset
    **config_kwargs,
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 1492, in load_dataset_builder
    data_files=data_files,
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 1238, in dataset_module_factory
    raise e1 from None
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 1180, in dataset_module_factory
    dynamic_modules_path=dynamic_modules_path,
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 533, in get_module
    local_path = self.download_loading_script(revision)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 513, in download_loading_script
    return cached_path(file_path, download_config=download_config)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/utils/file_utils.py", line 246, in cached_path
    download_desc=download_config.download_desc,
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/utils/file_utils.py", line 582, in get_from_cache
    raise ConnectionError(f"Couldn't reach {url} ({repr(head_error)})")
ConnectionError: Couldn't reach https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/datasets/2.0.0/datasets/eli5/eli5.py (ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /huggingface/datasets/2.0.0/datasets/eli5/eli5.py (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x126af5f98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))")))
```

The server isn't connect to the web due to safety concerns. Do I have a way to download manually?

Answer (score 0):

From the [datasets documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading#offline) that you might want to try.

> Even if you don’t have an internet connection, it is still possible to load a dataset. As long as you’ve downloaded a dataset from the Hub or  Datasets GitHub repository before, it should be cached. This means you can reload the dataset from the cache and use it offline.
>
> If you know you won’t have internet access, you can run  Datasets in full offline mode. This saves time because instead of waiting for the Dataset builder download to time out,  Datasets will look directly in the cache. Set the environment variable HF_DATASETS_OFFLINE to 1 to enable full offline mode.